# Problems dual booting - W2019 Server, CentOS, rufus, Dell Studio 1557

Tags: centos, grub2, system-installation, dual-boot, mbr

I have an oldish Dell Studio 1557 laptop (decent enough - 1TB Samsung SSD, 8GB RAM) on which I've installed Windows Server 2019 Standard from an .iso. I only used about 350GB for the  Windows install.

So, then I used the [rufus tool](https://rufus.ie) to write a CentOS-Stream-8 .iso to a USB stick (.iso is too big for a DVD) and then gave it about 400GB on the SSD.

I have tried **many** options with the rufus tool, but **every** time, I end up with a boot screen with **only** the CentOS option to boot into.

Now, I know that my Windows install hasn't disappeared, because when I start at the beginning (yet) again, my Windows partitions are still there and appear to be intact as far as I can tell.

I've done many dual boots with Fedora and that seems to work a treat - Fedora never overwrites the MBR and I have my Windows **plus** my Fedora after the process.

So, what I would like to know is: Is there any way that I can recover my Windows boot option **and** retain CentOS-Stream-8? Is there a file (GRUB? - I know virtually nothing about this area!) that I can edit or are there rufus options that I should be choosing (I've tried a few combos!).

Should I be using another tool to create the .iso?

The result of

```
sudo grep -i centos /etc/grub2.cfg
```

is the empty set!

### EDIT - following [`Nasir's comment`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622539/problems-dual-booting-w2019-server-centos-rufus-dell-studio-1557?noredirect=1#comment1164549_622539):

> Did you set the laptop to boot from the USB?

I both hit F2 on booting and changed the boot order back to 1) HDD, 2) USB **and** I also removed the USB altogether. In any case, even if the USB is present, unless you hit "any key to boot from USB" within 60s, it boots from the HDD anyway - so that's not the solution.

### EDIT following Nasir's [`second comment`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622539/problems-dual-booting-w2019-server-centos-rufus-dell-studio-1557#comment1164608_622539):

> Your question needs more clarity.

- Step 1: Install Windows 2019 Server on a partition ~ 250GB.
- Step 2: Windows works fine.
- Step 3: Reboot machine with a USB containing CentOS-Stream-8, while ensuring that the machine boots from USB
- Step 4: Configure CentOS-Stream-8 on a further (and distinct) ~ 350GB and let the install process run. Then, when the install finishes, hit the reboot button which appears post-installation.
- Step 5: Remove USB media (and also ensure that boot from HDD is enabled).
- Step 6: On reboot, the only option that I am offered is to boot into CentOS-Stream-8 and there is **no sign** of my Windows install.
- Step 7: Reinstall Windows. My original ~ 250GB Windows partition is still there - I just can't boot into it! After the Windows reinstall, I do the same thing as above for CentOS using different options from the rufus tool.

I'm looking to see if there's anything I can set on my new CentOS install that can "reveal" my original Windows install when I boot up. I hope this is now clear - if not, please let me know.

Any ideas/URLs/references/help much appreciated.

If you need any more info, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Did you set the laptop to boot from the USB?

Comment: @NasirRiley - thanks for your input, but that's not the issue - see the edit to my question!

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. Did you actually install CentOS? You said that if you remove the USB, it boots from the HDD where Windows is installed. Does Windows boot successfully at that point?

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit again to go through the process clearly - again, thanks for your input!